# Vuejs : Why my array result contains__ob__: Observer?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to iterate over an array and do some changes. but results contains some {ob: Observer} thing. I know this is part of Vuejs reactivity system but
I want to know how to overcome it.

my code :

```
axios.post(route('foo.bar'), data).then((resp) => {

resp.data.forEach((value)=>{
   value.path = value.path.split('\\', 1).join('\\')
    });
this.pathSearchResults = _.sortedUniqBy(resp.data, 'path');

console.log(resp.data);
}
```

Console :

```
 0: {__ob__: Observer}
 1: {path: "root\new1", id: 3, type: "file"}
 2: {path: "root\new1", id: 4, type: "file"}
 3: {path: "root\new1", id: 5, type: "file"}
 4: {path: "root\new1", id: 6, type: "file"}
 5: {path: "root\new1", id: 7, type: "file"}
 6: {__ob__: Observer}
 7: {__ob__: Observer}
 12: {path: "root\new1", id: 15, type: "directory"}
```

and main question is why some of array items is reactive and some are not

Comment: Objects will become reactive once you assign them to a Vue instance (like `this.data = resp.data`). I can't see that happening anywhere in your code. Please provide any additional code where `resp.data` is being assigned and/or modified.

Comment: Comment this => value.path = value.path.split('\\', 1).join('\\').And then check in console.Every element would be having observer then.

Comment: The only way I can think of for you to have some array values reactive and some not, is if you assign them using a specific index (like `this.data[index] = {path: "root\new1"}`) instead of pushing them (like `this.data.push({path: "root\new1"})` which Vue can detect to make the entries reactive). That might also be why the array indexes are not all sequential, and they jump from `7` to `12`.

Comment: @Bogdan updated